# Implement page scrolling (like hand tool in Acrobato Reader) in my Eclipse Plugin Editor

Tags: eclipse, plugins, interaction

I'm developing an Eclipse Plugin Editor that has a Flyout Palette with several tools in it (like selection and so on).

I was wondering how to add a special tool (let's call it "hand tool") that scrolls the page in the same way the "hand tool" of the Acrobat Reader scrolls the page of a PDF document.

I'm googling for some ideas of how to tackle this problem, but with no success, so far. Could you please give me some hint?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using GEF? My answer may be trivial, but i'm trying to throw in some ideas.

`org.eclipse.draw2d.Viewport` class has pair of `getViewLocation()`/`setViewLocation()` metods. It seems that using them you can scroll your view as desired.

Now you'll need a tool. Explore the hierarchy of `org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool` descendans to find some examples of desired behavior and create your own tool class for your functionality.